# сортировка по указанному значению столбца

Tags: mysql, sql

столбец содержит тип файла

`1|apk
2|exe
3|doc
4|pdf
5|cat //флаг каталога`

как отсортировать значения этого столбца чтобы `cat` был всегда вверху?

В результате должно получится

`5|cat
1|apk
2|exe
3|doc
4|pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT id, ext_col_name
FROM table_name
WHERE ...
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
     WHEN ext_col_name = 'cat' then -1
     ELSE id
  END
```

Comment: а как потом в выборке понять что это католог если мы его заменим на пустоту?

Comment: замена происходит __только__ в `ORDER BY` - выводите в `SELECT` те столбцы, которые вам нужны...

Comment: а как оставшиеся значения отсортировать не по алфавиту а по соседнему столбцу - `id`?

Comment: @user254893, приведите пример отсортированного (желаемого) результата

Comment: привел в вопросе